# How to update tablerow textview?

Tags: android, dynamic, row, android-tablelayout

I have this dynamic tablelayout:

```
 <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/main_table"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="2dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:stretchColumns="1" >
                    </TableLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
```

and the code:

```
tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);
...
// Create 5 columns to add as table data
            TextView labelid = new TextView(this);
            labelid.setId(count);
            labelid.setTextSize(20);
            labelid.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            labelid.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            labelid.setText(readxml.getID() + " ");
            labelid.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(labelid);

            // Create 5 columns to add as table data
            TextView labelname = new TextView(this);
            labelname.setId(count);
            labelname.setTextSize(20);
            labelname.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            labelname.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            labelname.setText(readxml.getName() + " ");
            labelname.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(labelname);
```

So, how can I update 1 row textviews texts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use GridView if it suits your issue, otherwise you may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3327612/1171484), it is what you need.

Comment: you mean to change the whole tablelayout to griview?

Comment: If you have dynamic rows and if they are a lot, then i think it would be more effective way to go.

Answer (score 0):

set Tags to TextView to call them back

for example

```
//label tag
labelid.setTag("labelid"+count);
//text tag
labelname.setTag("labelname"+count);
```

and to call labelid or labelname by position

```
//for example get first element added values

    int myid = 0;
    TextView labelid_text = (TextView) tl.findViewWithTag("labelid"+myid);
    TextView labelname_text = (TextView) tl.findViewWithTag("labelname"+myid);
```