# How to get tableRow value using Table Layout?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-tablelayout

I am beginner to learn android,I have assigned table row value by dynamically.
But I am not able to get the row value using on click listener method .
Can any one please help to solve the issues .

I have tried following methods

```
  @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.passbook);

            TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mytable);

            tl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        //obj.myShow(Passbook.this, v.getTag() + ": Row is clicked" );
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: post your code where are adding rows  dynamically .

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the onClickListener on the row not the layout.

Comment: ,Thanks for your response.I have multiple row .

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327599/get-all-tablerows-in-a-tablelayout just use that example and add a onClickListener for each row.

Comment: I got your point . I want only click-able row details not all table rows details

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what u need...try this and modify as u wish...

```
//...
tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
  TableRow t = (TableRow) view;
  TextView firstTextView = (TextView) t.getChildAt(0);
  TextView secondTextView = (TextView) t.getChildAt(1);
  String firstText = firstTextView.getText().toString();
  String secondText = secondTextView.getText().toString();
}
});
//...
```

Comment: tr means table layout or TableRow

Comment: how to create listener event without id

Comment: Check this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514097/how-do-i-get-values-from-a-dynamically-created-android-tablerow)