# TableRow is returning empty value in TableLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I have an Activity which does not have any layout file. Here there is a TableLayout which has 5 input rows. I want to get those edittext value from the rows. I have tried a lot but still unable to get the data from the rows.
Here is my activity.java file.Is there any other way to get the data from edittext? I have tried this.[Duplicate Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447221/how-to-get-tablerow-value-using-table-layout) but my app crashes with showing the error "TableRow can not be cast into EditText".

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ScrollView sv;
    TableLayout myTableLayout;

    String userName,
    firstName,
    city,
    zipCode,
    age;
    UserListAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List <User> userList;

    TableRow inputRow;
    String temp = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.i("TurnToTech", "Project Name - Dynamic table view");
        sv = new ScrollView(this);
        userList = new ArrayList <>();
        myTableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        drawScreen();
        recyclerView = new RecyclerView(this);
    }
    public void drawScreen() {
        // this might be a redraw, so we clean the view's container
        myTableLayout.removeAllViews();
        sv.removeAllViews();

        // special rows
        TableRow buttonRow = new TableRow(this);
        TableRow titleRow = new TableRow(this);

        //Alerts
        final AlertDialog alertDialog;
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Saveing");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Saved..");
        final AlertDialog alertDialog1;
        alertDialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog1.setTitle("Cancel");
        alertDialog1.setMessage("Rejected");

        // margins
        buttonRow.setPadding(20, 10, 20, 10);
        titleRow.setPadding(20, 10, 20, 10);

        // the title
        TextView title = new TextView(this);
        title.setText("Data input form");
        title.setTextSize(14);
        title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        titleRow.addView(title);
        titleRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        // the title tablelayout
        TableLayout titleTableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        titleTableLayout.addView(titleRow);

        // we add the title layout to the main one
        myTableLayout.addView(titleTableLayout);

        /// the 5 input rows
        inputRow(myTableLayout, "Name", 30, 10000); //returning ""
        inputRow(myTableLayout, "First Name", 30, 10001); //returning ""
        inputRow(myTableLayout, "Age", 3, 10002); //returning ""
        inputRow(myTableLayout, "City", 20, 10003); //returning ""
        inputRow(myTableLayout, "Zip Code", 6, 10004); //returning ""

        // the buttons table layout
        // purpose : right align for both buttons
        TableLayout buttonsLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        buttonRow.setPadding(20, 50, 40, 0);

        // the accept and cancel buttons
        Button btAccept = new Button(this);
        btAccept.setText("Save");
        btAccept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO here I want to get all the row value that I filled from the table and store the value inside the user object.
                User user = new User(userName, firstName, age, city, zipCode);

                userList.add(user);
                adapter = new UserListAdapter(userList, MainActivity.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
        Button btCancel = new Button(this);
        btCancel.setText("Cancel");
        btCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog1.show();
            }
        });
        buttonRow.addView(btAccept);
        buttonRow.addView(btCancel);
        buttonRow.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        buttonsLayout.addView(buttonRow);
        myTableLayout.addView(buttonsLayout);
        sv.addView(myTableLayout);
        setContentView(sv);
    }

    public void inputRow(TableLayout tl, String label, int inputSize, int inputID) {
        inputRow = new TableRow(this);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        EditText edit = new EditText(this);

        // some margin
        inputRow.setPadding(20, 10, 20, 0);
        tv.setText(label);
        edit.setMaxWidth(inputSize * 7);
        edit.setMinimumWidth(inputSize * 7);
        edit.setId(inputID);
        edit.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        inputRow.addView(tv);
        inputRow.addView(edit);
        tl.addView(inputRow);
    }
}
```

I mentioned a todo inside the onClick event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of `onClick()` for `btAccept`, you'll need to call something like this for each `EditText`:

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceType") EditText nameEditText = findViewById(10000);
String nameEntered = nameEditText.getText().toString();
.
.
.
```

One you've done this for all your `EditTexts`, you can store them in a `User` object.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion but this is a task. I would do that by adding table layout and table row in xml file but I need to do that pragmatically. Thanks.

Comment: This is not gonna happen. Compiler is showing error. Did you check that on your compiler? I am using android studio.

Comment: What's the error? I'm not going to recreate your entire project for you just to test it.

Comment: It is showing "Expected resource of type id". Compile time error.

Comment: That's not a compile time error. It's a Lint error because this is a silly way to do things. See my edit for how to suppress the error.

Comment: Yeah Got that a few minutes ago. Thanks.